# Trying to use interface's key/values to define the return type of a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

These are my types:

```
type TYPE_1 = "TYPE_1"
type TYPE_2 = "TYPE_2"
type TYPE_3 = "TYPE_3"

type RETURN_OBJECT = {
    KEY_1: TYPE_1,
    KEY_2: TYPE_2,
    KEY_3: TYPE_3
}
```

The goal is to build a function that will take a `key` of type `"KEY_1" | "KEY_2" | "KEY_3"` and will return a type of `"TYPE_1" | "TYPE_2" | "TYPE_3"`. And the relation between the `key` and the `return` is mapped by a `RETURN_OBJECT` type.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgmgBQKIH0CMUC8UBE9no4BQoksiqATFrvlcadHSgMw14WvEnjQBKSGAFU+AORQB5AEIApJAGEYNAN5Eo6qAGkkcdAC5yBNABo1G7bsoHmlUxq07W1ziyIBfIjzIwkAZSXYAsJikrIKMADaOBaEALoA3OoA9ElQAOoSfJq+AISwfkoAkr6GqGiejFBCooUS4hYl2NGOaDhQAD64MZRtnc26LAy8VTV1KEEiojTMGJ02HaWsngBmAK4AdgDGwACWAPbrUADmEMCiEADuEgBGAFYQ2wA8mlAQAB7AEOsAJgDOUABrCAgPbLKATELSOSKAB8AApGAZNABKAwQ8RQ8IRTSxKCqey-C47YCbAAWCN4yLxZns6k2AENftB+oQDPjaRyAE6nVacw4cIw4eI02keDl0xnM7o4Nki8VQbnAXn8mxCuUaMXihlMrqOQay+X2RXK2guNXyzXqDweIibA6-YAKiC-DDYE5nS43e7bOEs1rIxJQFKwAASxSg4ZmUAAtFAJJpbfbHdzftQ3adzlc7g9gL7pQHkqkYGGSpHONRY-HE+sHU7fmx0x6s97cyzBgWg0WSxGSsw2JWE3aa8nnQAWGjuzNenN5xyjnAd4PF8PhpB8PiZGNxzRAA)

Although the results seem fine. This is not working:

```
function getNewObject<K extends keyof RETURN_OBJECT>(type: K): RETURN_OBJECT[K] {
    switch(type) {
        case "KEY_1": {
            return "TYPE_1";
        }
        case "KEY_2": {
            return "TYPE_2";
        }
        case "KEY_3": {
            return "TYPE_3";
        }
    }
}

const res1 = getNewObject("KEY_1");  // THIS IS TYPE_1 - OK
const res2 = getNewObject("KEY_2");  // THIS IS TYPE_2 - OK
const res3 = getNewObject("KEY_3");  // THIS IS TYPE_3 - OK
const res4 = getNewObject("KEY_4");  // THIS IS ERROR - OK
```

Typescript is complaining about some errors.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Tim Perry's answer, I've come up with the following:

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgmgBQKIH0CMUC8UBE9no4BQoksiqATFrvlcadHSgMw14WvEnjQBKSGAFU+AORQB5AEIApJAGEYNAN5Eo6qAGkkcdAC5yBNABo1G7bsoHmlUxq07W1ziyIBfIkQBmAVwB2AMbAAJYA9n5QAOYQwKIQAO4SAEYAVhBBADyaUBAAHsAQfgAmAM5QANYQIKFeUALCYpKyCjAAfAAUjAaaAJQG9SLi0nKKANqaALpQqvYB4SXAdYKDTSMw-cuNwy0qZvbqFvq0nGg4dvsHjlbHBJRne-uHLAYcBCz39m4A3A8ATjE+X4RAZbZpjRgTdyeOZ+BZQf4lDDYaKxBLJNJBdo4Q6nHpfdQAegJsAAEgBJADKUEphlQGAAtFAJJoiDC4QjqMiYnFEql0sAsYc7njCcSYOSqTSbFBGczWfNFgi2FzUbyMQLsY53iKoETSTSpS4ZUyWWzFRASgAWGgonno-mCxyWnA6vXig1UpB8PgSPjG5lAA)

```
type TYPE_1 = "TYPE_1"
type TYPE_2 = "TYPE_2"
type TYPE_3 = "TYPE_3"

type RETURN_OBJECT = {
    KEY_1: TYPE_1,
    KEY_2: TYPE_2,
    KEY_3: TYPE_3
}

function getNewObject<K extends keyof RETURN_OBJECT>(type: K): RETURN_OBJECT[K] {
    const RETURN_OBJECT: RETURN_OBJECT = {
        KEY_1: "TYPE_1",
        KEY_2: "TYPE_2",
        KEY_3: "TYPE_3",
    };
    return RETURN_OBJECT[type]
}

/* ###################### */
/* #### TEST RESULTS #### */
/* ###################### */

const res1 = getNewObject("KEY_1");  // THIS IS TYPE_1 - OK
const res2 = getNewObject("KEY_2");  // THIS IS TYPE_2 - OK
const res3 = getNewObject("KEY_3");  // THIS IS TYPE_3 - OK
const res4 = getNewObject("KEY_4");  // THIS IS ERROR - OK
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems here:

- You don't have a `default` case in your switch statement, and TypeScript doesn't seem to be clever enough to know that the switch statement covers all possibilities in this case (I think it's incorrect, I can't any other cases). This is easily covered with a `default` case that throws an error, which is a good idea anyway in case of unexpected inputs
- Your type says not just that `getNewObject` returns a value from that map, but that it returns the value from the map that matches the input key. In this case that's true, but TypeScript isn't smart enough to prove the relationship between the parameter and the return value that's required to *prove* that that's true. I.e. It can't prove that your code won't return `TYPE_2` given an input of `KEY_1`, for example. You have three options there:

  - Cast the return value with `as RETURN_OBJECT[K]` (awkward, but useful for some cases)
  - Make the type more general, e.g. returning `RETURN_OBJECT[keyof RETURN_OBJECT]` rather than `RETURN_OBJECT[K]`
  - Make the code simpler, so that TypeScript can understand the relationship between the param and the return type, e.g. like so:

  ```js
  return ({
    "KEY_1": "TYPE_1",
    "KEY_2": "TYPE_2",
    "KEY_3": "TYPE_3"
  } as const)[type];
  ```

Personally, I would write your code using a fixed map object, rather than the switch statements, more along the lines of this:

```js
const TYPE_MAP = {
    "KEY_1": "TYPE_1",
    "KEY_2": "TYPE_2",
    "KEY_3": "TYPE_3"
} as const;

type KEYS = keyof typeof TYPE_MAP
type VALUES = typeof TYPE_MAP[KEYS];

function getNewObject<K extends KEYS>(type: K): typeof TYPE_MAP[K] {
    return TYPE_MAP[type];
}

const res1 = getNewObject("KEY_1");  // THIS IS TYPE_1 - OK
const res2 = getNewObject("KEY_2");  // THIS IS TYPE_2 - OK
const res3 = getNewObject("KEY_3");  // THIS IS TYPE_3 - OK
const res4 = getNewObject("KEY_4");  // THIS IS ERROR - OK
```

Obviously that's a bit reductive, you don't really need the function in this case, but for more complex real cases basing them on patterns like this will allow TypeScript to understand what you're doing here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used a minimal working example in the question, but in my real case `TYPE_1 2 and 3` are more complex object types, so I can't do the type map you've suggested. I've tried replace the switch for a `if else else` and also tried `RETURN_OBJECT[keyof RETURN_OBJECT]` but still no luck. I'm using function overloads to make it work. But I'm still trying to find a generic way to do it.

Comment: As far as I know, a direct object lookup of `obj[k]` is the only built-in way to make TypeScript infer `OBJ[K]` as the resulting type - anything else is going to give you a slightly more general type, because it would require complex flow tracing for TS to infer the relationship between the variables. If you can't do that or something equivalent, then you'll need to either cast each result or make the result type a bit more general to match.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tim. Starting from your answer, I've found a way to do what I was looking for. I've posted an answer as well.